# How can I get the missing dates from a hash range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm getting some data from my model and using `.count`, so I'm being given a hash range as a result.

```
where(:created_at => start_date.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day).
    group("date(applicants.created_at)").count
```

The output looks like this:

```
{"2015-10-06"=>1, "2015-07-09"=>2, "2015-07-13"=>3, "2015-07-14"=>2, "2015-08-14"=>3, "2015-08-27"=>1}
```

The problem is, I now need to fill out a date and a 0 value for all missing dates between the range. However, it being a hash, I'm struggling to search through the data.

So far, what I have does not find the date in the range; ever.

```
def dates_chart_series(orders, start_date, end_date)
  orders_by_day = orders
    .where(:created_at => start_date.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
    .group("date(applicants.created_at)")
    .count

  puts orders_by_day

  (start_date.to_date..end_date.to_date).map do |date|
    puts orders_by_day.select { |key, value|  key == date  }
    puts date
  end.inspect
end
```

The above code is taken from a RailsCast where an object (or array of objects) is returned. Not a hash. I've tried to adapt it using `.select` but I'm not having much luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = (start_date.to_date..end_date.to_date).each_with_object({}) do |date, hash|
  hash[date] = orders_by_day.fetch(date.to_s, 0)
end
```

Should return a new hash with each date as a key and 0 as the default value if the date doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you! Although each with object didn't seem to work, I've ended with: 
hash = Hash.new
    (start_date.to_date..end_date.to_date).each do |date|
      hash[date] = orders_by_day.fetch(date.to_s, 0)
    end

Comment: Cool, ah I got the parameters `|hash, date|` the wrong way around as usual.